# Multivariate linear regression ends up with 'NaN' sometimes

Tags: python, linear-regression, nan

I tried to implement multivariate linear regression from scratch and it works pretty well actually. When I was testing it with a toy dataset, I run into sometimes the predictions were 'NaN'. I know what are the possible NaN reasons though, I couldn't understand which one causes it in my script.
Note: with 0.0001 learning rate and 1.000.000 iterations, I got a really good line for the dataset though, when learning rate is 0.001 and the number of iterations is 1.000.000, the predictions were NaN.

Here is the script:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import numpy as np

class MultivariateLinearRegression():

#constructor
def __init__(self, learning_rate, learning_algorithm, epoch_num):
    self.learning_rate = learning_rate
    self.learning_algoritm = learning_algorithm
    self.epoch_num = epoch_num
    self.theta = 0
    self.training_sample = 0


def train(self, X, Y):
    Y = Y.reshape((Y.size, 1))
    if len(X.shape) == 1:
        X = X.reshape((X.size, 1)) 
    bias = np.ones([X.shape[0], 1])
    X = np.concatenate((X, bias), 1)

    self.theta = np.zeros([X.shape[1], 1])
    self.training_sample = X.shape[0]
    cost_history = []
    for i in range (self.epoch_num):
        hypothesis = X.dot(self.theta)
        cost_func = np.transpose(X).dot(np.subtract(hypothesis, Y))
        gradient = (self.learning_rate / self.training_sample) * cost_func
        self.theta = np.subtract(self.theta, gradient)
        cost_history.append(self.theta)

    return cost_history


def predict(self, X):
    X = np.array(X)
    bias = np.ones([1]).reshape((1,1))
    if len(X.shape) == 1:
        X = X.reshape((X.size, 1)) 
    X = np.concatenate((X, bias))      
    return np.transpose(X).dot(self.theta)[0] # [63,1]



datas = pd.read_csv('pattern_recognition_data.txt').to_numpy()
X = datas[0:25,0]
Y = datas[0:25:,1]
X_test = datas[25:29, 0]
Y_test = datas[25:29, 1]

mlr = MultivariateLinearRegression(0.001, 'gradient descent', 1000000) # 0.0001 ve 1.000.000
mlr.train(X, Y)

Y_pred = []
for x in X_test:
    print('X : ', x)
    Y_pred.append(mlr.predict([x]))
plt.plot(X, Y, 'bs')
plt.plot(X_test, Y_pred, 'r')
```

Thanks in advance

The dataset:

39,144

47,220

45,138

47,145

65,162

46,142

67,170

42,124

67,158

56,154

64,162

56,150

59,140

34,110

42,128

48,130

45,135

17,114

20,116

19,124

36,136

50,142

39,120

21,120

44,160

53,158

63,144

29,130

25,125

69,175

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9d395e99df0da6f3bee498d6b914b80420190810115220/91bfe6c225c5b90b6d5f2a102e0788ba20190810115220/43e458 : here is the data
import statements :
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
I also updated the code with import statements

Comment: Thank you for the data link, it is stating that I must make a legal agreement before downloading.

Comment: I'm not sure why such a statement is referred sir. I'm putting it into my post. Please check it above.